# Angular: setting environment variables without cli

Tags: angular, deployment

I am working on an angular2 app created by another dev, with almost no documentation. The project has no been built using cli and making it a cli angular project implies too many work.

There is gulpfile allowing to create a dist folder using systemjs.

I would like now to set environment variables (prod, dev, staging, etc..) the more easily possible.

What is the best way to do it without using angular cli?

Comment: Without knowing more I'd recommending looking at some gulp packages that could swap out an environment file. Essentially mimicking what the cli does so well :)

Comment: Do you mean this kind of things ? [http://jspm.io/0.17-beta-guide/conditional-loading.html](http://jspm.io/0.17-beta-guide/conditional-loading.html)

Comment: yep thats the concept. looks pretty promising

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to LLai, as explained in commentary:

> Without knowing more I'd recommending looking at some gulp packages that could swap out an environment file. Essentially mimicking what the cli does so well :)

I used conditionnal loading.